# What's the maximum number of eSIM cards that can be saved on a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra?

Tags: samsung, android-13, esim, android-14, samsung-galaxy-s-23

What's the maximum number of eSIM cards that can be saved on a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra?

I found https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS22/comments/yco7om/how_many_esims_can_be_present_on_an_s22_ultra/ but that's for S22 and the answers vary between 2, 3, 4 and unlimited.

I'm curious to know for Android 13 and 14.